# How can I do a res.render to a pug file without having a views directory in a node.js/express application?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I received a project which already had a directory structure.
In this directory structure there is no 'views' directory (like in a normal node.js/express application?).

See below the structure:

```
- site
  - config
      - assets
          default.js
          development.js
      - env
          default.js
          development.js
      - lib
          app.js
          express.js
          logger.js
          pug-routes.js
          socket.io.js
      config.js
  - modules
      - core
          - client
              - app
                  config.js
                  init.js
              - config
                  core.client.route-filter.js
                  core.client.routes.js
                  core-admin.client.routes.js
              - controllers
                  header.client.controller.js
                  home.client.controller.js
              - css
              - directives
              - services
              - views
          - server
              - controllers
                  core.server.controller.js
              - routes
                  core.server.routes.js
              - views
                  layout.server.view.html
      - website
          - client
              - css
              - img
              - js   
          - server
              contact.pug
              homescreen.pug
  - node_modules
  - public
  - scripts
  package.json
  server.js
```

There is a mail function on the contact form. This works all fine.
But when the mail function succeeded or failed I want to get a modal with some information. The modal is already created. 
In previous applications I did that like this:

```
if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.render('homescreen', {
        feedback:
        '<span lang="en">Your message cannot be sent.</span>'
      });
    } else {
      console.log('sended');
      res.render('homescreen', {
        feedback:
        '<span lang="en">Your message has been sent.</span>'
      });
    }
```

And then on the 'homescreen.pug' this:

```
if feedback
     include functions/modal
     +createModal({htmlClass: 'feedbackModal', closable: true})
         .text-center!=feedback
```

But the res.render is not working. It keeps getting an error while res.redirect is working.
It says this error on res.render:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "homescreen" in views directory "C:\Users\name\Desktop\the-new-website"

But there is no 'views' directory in my whole project.

This is something in express.js:

```
module.exports.initViewEngine = function (app) {
    app.engine('server.view.html', hbs.express4({
        extname: '.server.view.html'
    }));
    app.set('view engine', 'server.view.html');
    app.set('views', path.resolve('./'));
```

When I change the app.set('views'...) to another path, it has like a endless loop with redirecting.

The redirect is working like this:

```
res.redirect('/static/index');
```

And I created that like this in pug-routes.js:

```
module.exports = {
  '/index': {
    template: 'modules/website/server/homescreen.pug'
  }
}
```

So what can I do to res.render to the homescreen.pug with a message (feedback).

Comment: What happens when you change your `app.set('views', path.resolve('./'));`
 as `app.set('views', __dirname);` ?

Comment: Have you tried `res.render('modules/website/server/homescreen', ..`?

Comment: @David R Then i will get an error in core.server.controller.js: "exports.renderIndex = function (req, res) {
  res.render('modules/core/server/views/index', {
   
  });
};"

Comment: @Molda I get the following error: Error: Failed to lookup view "modules/website/server/homescreen" in views directory "C:\Users\name\Desktop\the-new-website"

Comment: I just noticed you have set `app.engine` to use handlebars and it's looking for `.server.view.html` extention so it's ignoring pug files. Well that's my best guess.

Comment: You can try to add the extension: `res.render('modules/website/server/homescreen.pug'` so express will use pug instead of html extension when looking up a view.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! @Molda

Comment: @Molda Please write answer. I want to upvote it. Your comment saved my day. Thank you